# How can I write this active record? (Rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three model:

- raw_coupon
- coupon
- store

If I'm looping through raw_coupons, how can I save it as a coupon only if the same coupon_code doesn't already exist for that store? Here is code to make it more clear:

```
raw_coupon.each do |raw_coupon|
  coupon = Coupon.new
  coupon.store_id = raw_coupon.store_id
  coupon.coupon_code = raw_coupon.coupon_code

  coupon.save if [coupon_code for this store doesn't already exist]
end
```

How to I write out the **[coupon_code for this store doesn't already exist]**

**NOTE:** more than one store can be using the same coupon code hence I need to check if the same coupon_code exists for that store specifically.

**EDIT:** Here are the model associations:

- raw_coupon: has_one :coupon
- coupon: belongs_to :raw_coupon   &&  belongs_to:store
- store: has_many :coupons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a unique validation to Coupon and watch out for errors when you call `coupon.save`:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :coupon_code, :uniqueness => { :scope => :store_id }
    #...
end
```

[The `:scope` limits](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness) the uniqueness check to the coupon codes for the coupon's `store_id`.

You should also add a unique index to `coupons` on the `store_id` and `coupon_code` as an extra layer of protection.

Comment: What about nil? A store can have multiple coupons in the system where the coupon_code is nil.

Comment: @Hopstream: A coupon without a code? Sounds odd to me but there is the [`:allow_nil`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_nil) option for that and multiple NULLs are allowed in unique indexes.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this in the conditional (since otherwise using validation it will always throw an error) -- and processing thousands of coupons like this will throw thousands of errors.

Comment: @Hopstream: You can try to count the matches but that would be an ugly kludge, an object should be responsible for ensuring its own internal validity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use find_or_initialize_by helper. I wouldnt recommend find_or_create_by helper since it wont raise error if validations fail on create.

```
raw_coupon.each do |raw_coupon|
  coupon = Coupon.find_or_initialize_by_store_id_and_coupon_code(raw_coupon.store_id, raw_coupon.coupon_code)
  coupon.save! if coupon.new_record? #This just saves you from extra DB calls.
end
```

i used save! to raise an exception if your validation fails. Just FYI